# Writte errors to a file

Tags: r, save

I am using the R programming language and I have a program that I deliver to some clients.

I currently use the function `sink()` to save some inputs to the program and measure time performance but in case there is an error I would also like to save it into the file. Does somebody know a neat way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the `sink()` manual, it has a `message` option:

```
 ## capture all the output to a file.
 zz <- file("all.Rout", open = "wt")
 sink(zz)
 sink(zz, type = "message")
 try(log("a"))
 ## back to the console
 sink(type = "message")
 sink()
 try(log("a"))
```